# Sage Pay - use of merchantSessionKey in Payment transaction

Tags: credit-card, opayo

I have been reading the Sage Pay API documentation and had a question about the use of merchantSessionKey when sending a Payment transaction.

Do I always need to send the merchantSessionKey used when I created the cardIdentifier when making a Payment? Or can it be *any* valid merchantSessionKey?

I am trying to work out whether I need to save the merchantSessionKey locally alongside the cardIdentifier when I call POST /card-identifiers so I can use in future transactions associated with this cardIdentifier.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to supply the same merchant session key when you do the initial transaction. If you have saved the CardIdentifier to use at a later date, you don't need to supply a merchant session key when you do subsequent transactions...

(remember to flag the transaction as "reusable":true, though)

Comment: it gives error The Security Code(CV2) is required